# Private static property variable leads to null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, static-initialization

I have set a private static properties object to load in some configuration for my factory class in the constructor of factory class.

```
public class BussinessServiceFactory {
    private static final BussinessServiceFactory factory = new BussinessServiceFactory();
    public static BussinessServiceFactory createBussinessServiceFactory(){
        return factory;
    }
    private BussinessServiceFactory(){
        InputStream in = BussinessServiceFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("factory/bussinessservice.properties");
        try {
            bsConfig.load(in);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
    private static Properties bsConfig = new Properties();
    public <T> T createBussinessService(Class<T> clazz){
        try {
            String clazzName = clazz.getSimpleName();
            String name = bsConfig.getProperty(clazzName);
            return (T) Class.forName(name).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | ClassNotFoundException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I initialize the class, it throws `NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at factory.BussinessServiceFactory.<init>(BussinessServiceFactory.java:15)
    at factory.BussinessServiceFactory.<clinit>(BussinessServiceFactory.java:8)
    ... 24 more
```

Then if I change the properties object into non-static object, the problem is solved. But I am still confused by the reason why would this happen and how it could be solved in this way.

Comment: Well, the exception says the issue is in *testFindOrder* and you are showing us *testPageQuery*. How do we help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static initializers are done topdown. So the static field `factory` is initialized when the class `BussinessServiceFactory` is loaded. This static initializer calls the constructor for `BussinessServiceFactory`, and so therefore, eventually, loads a reference to the static field `bsConfig`. This field is not yet initialized at this point, since we are still in the static initializer block for the `factory` field. Hence, the NullPointerException.

Fix this either 1) reordering the `bsConfig` field to be above the `factory` field, or better yet, don't have this interfield dependency by making the `bsConfig` field an instance field (which is what you did to fix it, and i believe is the best way to fix such an issue).

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4 for details about order of static initialization.

*addendum*: 
the stacktrace reveals the source of your problem. The `clinit` in the stacktrace stands for *cl*ass *init*, and therefore, you can tell that the issue is loading of a class.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is very helpful!